# How often do you buy (a new car/new cars)?

Tags: word-usage

With a quick Google search it is clearly evident that the singular version (a new car) is more fitting than the plural one (new cars) in the questions below. Bear in mind the question is addressed to the **average person.**

**Singular:**

> How often do you buy **a new car**?

**Plural:**

> How often do you buy **new cars**?

The question is can either one be used, and if so which is more natural?

Comment: Grammatically, either one is OK. Logically, more context is needed.

Comment: Nothing special. Either a friend or a car dealer asks that question and the speakers says, let's say, "I buy a new car every five years".

Comment: If you are asking about "I buy a new car every five years", then it has to be "a". You should add to your question for clarity.

Comment: The issue is I am the one who is asking the question to a friend or maybe an acquaintance. A dealer could ask this question to a customer too. So I don't know much about the person who is being asked except the fact they are average persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular. The consumer buys only one, no matter how often.

The same question to a car dealer may require the plural form.

Comment: Hmm...I have 2 cars. Possibly I could buy 2 at the same time.

Comment: then you would be in huge a minority & not really a target of the question - part-way between consumer & dealer

Comment: The problem is the question is not clear. Really that is the point I am making. Otherwise it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: In my opinion (see what I did there? ;) unless you really need to cover every possible eventuality, if you're asking someone in general conversation about their automobile-buying habits, the first would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin "in general conversation", yeah! That's it.